# Visual Mode is Missing in Wordpress Editing Page

Tags: wordpress, plugins, tinymce, themes

One of my clients' Wordpress sites has a problem with the TinyMCE editor. Their site does not show the tab to switch between text and visual mode while editing a page. The look of the TinyMCE editor is a little different from a normal Wordpress installation. I thought it could be from a plugin or the theme. I tried uninstalling all plugins and also used the default Wordpress theme, with no luck. Any thoughts? (by default, editing is in text mode.)

Comment: Hello: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Sounds like a Javascript file is missing or blocked by security policy. What's the error on your Web browser's Javascript console?

Comment: Thanks. The console has no error. I even replaced the whole wp-include folder with a fresh one from Wordpress Installation. No luck yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I fixed it myself.
In the `usermeta` table in the database, for that user, the meta_key `rich_editing` was set to `false`. I changed it to `true` and it now works fine.
However, although I managed to fix it, still don't know what had caused the issue.